# What is meant by the term "inplace"

Tags: terminology

I have a vague sense of the meaning of this term, usually in the context of data structures and algorithms which happen to rely upon swap variables to shuttle data around containers and what not. But I'd like to hear some richer definitions and nuances to people's knowledge of this term. Taking a shot at it myself I'd say doing something in place (interesting subquestion, what verbs can come before inplace? moving inplace? transferring inplace? copying inplace?) is to transfer elements of container data from one memory location to another without recourse to a second copy of the whole container.

Comment: From what I gather, it's making an operation on the data, without using more space than what's occupied by the data

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm ?   "an algorithm which transforms input using a data structure with a small, constant amount of extra storage space. The input is usually overwritten by the output as the algorithm executes."

Answer (score 1):

"inplace" usually means "with O(1) additional space".

Answer (score 0):

This term is often used to indicate an alternative to some operation that would normally involve some kind of a copying operation. The alternative achieves the same results, but avoids the copying procedure or operation, whatever the case may be.

One example comes from C++. Before the C++11 revision to the language, adding an element to a container could not avoid a copy operation of some kind, which could get expensive when the container has a non-trivial object.

If a completely new class instance is to be added to the container, it was pretty much a foregone conclusion that what ends up happening is: 1) class instance construction, 2) a copy construction, and 3) destruction of the first instance.

C++11 added certain language features that make it possible to avoid copying, with the new class instance ending up getting construct "in place", or "emplace" inside the container.